# Degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})})$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to obtain an upper bound for $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})}): \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})]$.

I can show that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})})$. But I'm not sure how to use this.

I was told that it was possible to bound it above by $2$ but I can't see the justification for this.

I think I'm missing something obvious but would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a square root. The set up is that you are
looking at an extension $K(\sqrt{a})/K$ where $a\in K$. This has degree $1$
if $a$ is a square in $K$; it has degree $2$ if $a$ is not a square in $K$.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Thanks